# При добавлении внешнего ключа пропали товары в админке

Tags: python, django

Почему при добавлении внешнего ключа пропадают все товары?

models.py

```
class GoodImgBackend(models.Model):
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to='goods/backend/', blank=True)

class Good(models.Model):
    ...
    это новый внешний ключ
    img_backend=models.ForeignKey(GoodImgBackend, blank=True)
```

Как мне исправить, что бы все товары, которые были до добавления нового внешнего ключа?

Answer (score 1):

Было достаточно добавить в поле внешнего ключа ForeignKey null=True, т.е. в результате поле должно выглядеть так:

```
img_backend=ForeignKey(GoodImgBackend, blank=True, null=True)
```